# Button inside Android ConstraintLayout refuses to show multi-character text centered in horizontal orientation

Tags: android, text, android-constraintlayout, android-button

I'm using ConstraintLayout with Flow Helper object in order to organize some buttons on the screen.
The buttons are not centering the text as it should.

I have the following button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height = "0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:text="x909"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
```

As you can see there are many values that will affect the size and positioning of the button upon rendering.

The button positioning is working fine. **The problem is the text positioning inside the button**.

So, in the button above the text:

- x909 will show as ONLY an 'x' centered in the button, with maxLines = "1"
- x909 shows as ONLY an 'x9' centered in the button , with maxLines = "2" , ***BUT the 9 shows below 'x'***
- x909 shows as ONLY an 'x90' centered in the button, with maxLines ="3" , **BUT the x is on top, the 9 below it and the 0 below the 9**

**The text is broken up into its characters and somehow a newline character is placed between characters so it displays vertically from top to down. I'm using LTR orientation**

***I've tried many different combinations*** using textAlignment, maxLines, lines, minLines, all types of gravity but every time the text is broken up into its characters and displayed vertically.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution by guiding myself with an old project I had:

Inside the Fragment onViewCreated method which loads the ConstraintLayout, I create a ViewGroup object which sets up a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener object.

As the buttons are laid out, I change their singleLine attribute to true and even change the TypeFace of the text.

Here's the code: It works perfectly:

```
         ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;
        final ViewGroup myGroup = group.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.graphlay);

        if(myGroup!=null){

            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    for(int u = 0; u < myGroup.getChildCount(); u++){
                        View view01 = myGroup.getChildAt(u);
                        try{
                            Button button = (Button)view01;
                            Log.d("inspectme","button: " + button.getText());
                            button.setTypeface(MainActivity.typeface0024);
                            button.setSingleLine(true);

                        }catch (Exception exx){

                        }
                    }

                    myGroup.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);




                }


            };



            myGroup.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
        }
```

**I still would like to know the way of doing this in the XML instead of creating a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener object!!**